# How can I create and use a fake directory structure?

Tags: php, mysql, directory, structure

I have been looking at some sites that pretend that there is a directory structure in the URL and wondered 'how?'.

I am taking control of a website at work and have looked over the code. They have a database for all the pages and they are created dynamically.

I can get the homepage working on my local server but I don't have a clue as to where to start with the fake directory structure. An example is `http://www.bankcharges.com/bank-charges-advice/` - there is no directory for this but the content is in the database.

How have they done this?

The code this I think is related to is:

`index.php`:

```
<?php

    include('includes/functions.php');

    $activeTab = "navhome"; 
    $sent = false;

    $title = (isset($_GET['title']))? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['title']) : 'Home';    
    $title = str_replace('-',' ', $title);

    if($title != '') {  

        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM contents 
                WHERE name LIKE '%$title%'
                LIMIT 1";

        $result = @mysql_query($sql);       
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);      
    }

    //Set page title
    $pagetitle = (isset($row['name']) && $title != 'Home')? ucwords($row['name']) : "Bank Charges";
?>
```

`functions.php`:

```
<?php

include('database.php');
include('settings.php');

//Nice URL's
function url($str){
$arr = array('!','"','£','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','+','{','}',':','@','~','<','>','?','|',',','.','\\','/',';',']','[','\'');    
$str = str_replace($arr,"", str_replace(" ","-",strtolower($str))); 
return $str;        
}

function isEven($v){
    if($v % 2 == 0) return true;        
}

?>
```

Answer (score 7):

mod_rewrite is the apache module that allows this to occur.  Other web servers have their own implementations.

For a beginners guide, check out [this blog post](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 3):

Might be a bit complicated if you don't know where to begin... you have to rewrite the URLs with something like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /index.php?url=$0 [L,QSA]
```

And then when you go to a URL like `http://www.bankcharges.com/bank-charges-advice/`, your server will actually call up `http://www.bankcharges.com/index.php?url=bank-charges-advice/`. And then in index.php you can handle that query however you want (usually by pulling something from the database). Start by learning `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 0):

search for url rewrite on google.

here is a [guide from apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)